# How do i find t given 3 = t!+(t+1)!/t!+t!

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am a high school student, so I apologize for what might be a simple question. The original question is:

> There are an equal number of boys and girls in a class and they are seated in a row so that
>    no two boys sit next to each other and no two girls sit next to each other. If one more
>   student is added to the class the number of seating arrangements with the original
>   conditions is tripled. How many students were in the class originally?

from this I wrote 3(t!+t!) = t!+(t+1)!, but the problem is I have no idea how to evaluate and solve for t. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should write with MathJax, but whatever: **at least** use parentheses for clear writing! Did you mean $\;3=t!+\frac{(t+1)!}{t!}+t!\;$ , or $\;\frac{t!+(t+1)!}{t!}+t!\;$ , or maybe $\;\frac{t!+(t+1)!}{t!+t!}\;$ ...??

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I've just started using math stackexchange so I actually don't know how to do anything yet. I'll get MathJax, and I meant the third example you gave

Comment: Notice that $t! + t! = 2t!$ which is different from $(2t)!$ in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 3):

The counting is off. Note that for each of the $t!$ arrangements of boys, there are $t!$ arrangements of girls. Thus there are $2t!t!$ different arrangements, where we multiply by $2$ to account for whether we start with boys or girls.

Thus the equation becomes 
$$3(2(t!)^2)=t!(t+1)!,$$
where there is no $2$ on the right hand side because whichever gender with $t+1$ members must appear first and last. To solve this, divide by $(t!)^2$ to get $6=t+1$, and therefore $t=5$.

Answer (score 2):

**Assertion:** $$3(t!+t!)=t! + (t+1)!$$

---

**Evaluation:** $$\begin{align} 3\cdot 2t! = 6t! &= t! + (t+1)! \\ 5t! &= (t+1)! \\ 5 &= \frac{(t+1)!}{t!} \\ &= t+1 \\ t &= 5-1 \end{align}$$

---

**Answer:** $$\boxed{t=4}$$

---

I recently got a new phone with a new iOS so tell me if the formatting of my answer is not as it should be, and I will fix it.

Comment: Surprisingly, the answer to the question is 10 students, which would mean that t=5. Would this be an error on the creator of the test's part or my part?

Comment: @T.Ou You got the number of arrangements right with the factorials, and you multiplied by $3$ because of the new student tripling the arrangement conditions. Must be the creator's mistake then, I guess.